# Relationship between fields - classes OpenErp

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, relation

I need to relate a field first declared on `product.py` to a custom module i'm making.

The fields are in the `product.product` class as follows:

```
_name = "product.product"
_description = "Product"
_table = "product_product"
_inherits = {'product.template': 'product_tmpl_id'}
_inherit = ['mail.thread']
_order = 'default_code,name_template'
_columns = {
    'codigo_n' : fields.char('Codigo Arancelario', size=64),
    'tec_esp' : fields.char('Especificaciones tecnicas', size=72),
    'qty_available': fields.function(_product_qty_available, type='float', string='Quantity On Hand'),
    'virtual_available': fields.function(_product_virtual_available, type='float', string='Quantity Available'),
    'incoming_qty': fields.function(_product_incoming_qty, type='float', string='Incoming'),
    'outgoing_qty': fields.function(_product_outgoing_qty, type='float', string='Outgoing'),
    'price': fields.function(_product_price, type='float', string='Price', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
    'lst_price' : fields.function(_product_lst_price, type='float', string='Public Price', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
    'code': fields.function(_product_code, type='char', string='Internal Reference'),
    'partner_ref' : fields.function(_product_partner_ref, type='char', string='Customer ref'),
```

It's not all the product.py code btw, but it shows the two fields i need to relate i.e. the first two ones `codigo_n` and `tec_esp`, and i'm inheriting the class in my custom module as follows:

```
_name = 'certificados.line'
_description = "Items del Certificado"
_inherit = 'product.product'

def multi_a_b(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context):
        res[record.id] = record.Cantidad * record.Precio_Unitario_Declarado
    return res

_columns = {
    'codigo_n' : fields.char( 'Codigo Arancelario'),
    'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Material'),
    'Descripcion_Arancelaria' : fields.many2one('product.category','Descripcion Arancelaria', required=True, change_default=True, domain="[('type','=','normal')]"), 
    'tec_esp' : fields.char('Especificaciones tecnicas'),
    'Cantidad' : fields.float('Cantidad'), 'Unidad_de_Medida': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Unidad de Medida'),
    'Precio_Unitario_Declarado' : fields.float('Precio Unitario Declarado'), 'Moneda' : fields.many2one('res.currency', 'Moneda'),
    'Valor_En_Divisas' : fields.function(multi_a_b, type='integer', string='Valor En Divisas'),
    'requisicion_id' : fields.many2one('certificados.certificados', 'Certificados de No Produccion', ondelete='cascade'),
    'Cantidad_Consumida' : fields.float('Cantidad Consumida'), 'Cantidad_Disponible' : fields.float('Cantidad Disponible'),
}
```

As far as i know if i inherit in `_name` the original object, i should inherit all it's fields and then adding the new ones declared on the new class.

Problem is, i'm not really sure how to inherit these two fields being of type `char`, already tried `one2many` and then calling them by `many2one` in the custom module but it returns a `None` relation, how could i achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to add these fields codigo_n and tec_esp in product.product object by inheriting it in your custom module ? or Do you want to add these fields in certificados.line object ?

Comment: They are already in product.product, what i want is to relation them on certificados.line object, right now they exist in both, but unrelated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can already see product.product is many2one in certificados.line object so you can use it via product_id.tec_esp and product_id.codigo_n for certificados.line object.

You can use fields.related field if you want to show these fields, codigo_n and tec_esp, in certificados.line object with the same value as in product.product.

Define tec_esp in certificados.line object like this:

```
'tec_esp': fields.related('product_id', 'tec_esp', type='char', size=64, string='Especificaciones tecnicas', store=True, readonly=True)
```

and the same way define for codigo_n.

fields.related is working when you will save the record of certificados.line with any value defined in product. As soon as you will save, those both fields will automatically fill up with the values defined in that linked product.

Comment: Omg thank you very much, i'll try it as soon as i wake up, lol, it's very late here, but i'm pretty sure it'll work, 'cause i had some idea about it, but some trouble with the attributes of the field as well, so thank you again! I'll try it...

Comment: Well, i tried and put some content in this new field, on product, but doesn't loads anything into cartificados.line, another weird thing is that it doesn't loads automatically when i choose a product on 'product_id'

Comment: You mean, these fields relates to an already related (many2one) field, like product_id, but i think it should come directly from the parent object (product.product) although i think your approach is right tho...

Comment: By adding related fields, it will come when you will save the record of cartificados.line with value of product in it. As soon as you will save it's record, value of tec_esp and codigo_n from selected product, come into tec_esp and codigo_n fields of cartificados.line.

Comment: Yes, but it was giving me an error, says something like: "Operation can not be completed, probably due to the following:
- Deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still have references to it
- Creation / update: a mandatory field is not entered correctly"

Comment: Maybe using the same name for both product.py and certificados.line fields is causing the problem? i'll try changing them on certificados.line

Comment: Nothing, keeps giving the " Deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still have references to it - Creation / update: a mandatory field is not entered correctly"

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem was the `_inherit = 'product.product'` it tried to override the original products and fields on them in the `product.py` file. I removed it and now it works!

So, your solution is awesome and works like a charm, thank you very very much Priyesh Solanki!